# 'No function was found that matched the signature provided' with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am attempting to make it so that when you drag an image from your files or the internet into the drop area it makes an image on the page take the SRC of that image. This seems like it would be easy, but I have looked all over the internet 
and have been unable to figure this out. Chrome throws the error:

> 'No function was found that matched the signature provided'.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function dropHandler(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      img = new Image();
      fileTransferred = ev.dataTransfer.items[0];
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ev.dataTransfer.items[0]);
      ev.dataTransfer.items.clear();
      ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
    }

    function dragOverHandler(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);">
    <p>Drag a picture here.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Remove `event`. [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) is non-standard.

Comment: could it be that, as your image is not on the server you have to provide full source of it from computer. otherwise it gives error maybe.

Comment: What should I do instead, Xufox? Also, this is on a server. My bigger project is at onlymx13.github.io/cesium-color-helper, in which the drag-and-drop function throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of checking, I found out that you should make it behave as a file, not an item. Demo that shows this is **[here.](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=ffad7d60cb72c8fa46b042c08abbc5c5)**

JS

```
function dropHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    img = new Image();
    fileTransferred = ev.dataTransfer.files[0];
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileTransferred);
    ev.dataTransfer.items.clear();
    ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
  alert(img.src);
}

function dragOverHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Your demo actually still throws the error, at least on my Windows 10 PC with the latest Chrome.

Comment: The error comes from revokeObjectURL as i checked. But if you assign a img element to have the img.src as src it will display image i tested. @HelloGoodbye

Comment: Right, I was dragging images from the web rather than images from my computer. But even when I drag one from my computer, I get a 404 error that it was unable to get the file. This is on a server rather than my computer, on which I get a different error because the file is blob:null rather than blob:http:.